# Minor Grid Lines in a matplotlib Log Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, gridlines, xticks

I can plot minor grid lines in a matplotlib log plot like this:

[image]

```
lx = [6,60,100,6]
ly = [40,6,100,40]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1);

plt.plot(lx, ly,'-',  color='k', linewidth=5)

ax.set_yscale('log')

ax.grid(True, which='both', color='b')
ax.minorticks_on()
```

But when I change the data to:

```
ly = [40,0.6,10000,40]
```

I lose my minor grid lines on the log y axis:

[image]

How can I get my minor grid lines back please?

Comment: Hmm. I get this output https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4wox.png.

Comment: Turning my computer off and on again solved this!